# Knockout-KendoTreeView checkbox binding to model with AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, checkbox, kendo-ui

I have an AJAX call that is populating a KendoTreeView list of products.  For each product, there are an additional 45 options that the user can select (boolean either on/off) that I've chosen to use checkboxes for each.

Instead of exponentially killing the DOM with a growing tree (45 times however many products), I've chosen to use a KendoWindow that holds the model for the additional options.  Each time a product is selected, an ajax call is run to get the current options in the database and opens the KendoWindow.

The model backing the data has a Checked boolean property which should pre-populate the window, and also get updated whenever the user makes a change.  This is the part I haven't been able to figure out how to do.  I've looked through a few other posts (such as [Working with a list of checkboxes in knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736136/working-with-checkboxes-in-knockoutjs)), but haven't been able to get it to work correctly.

```
<div class="optionSection" data-bind="with: ProductOptions">
        <div id="ProductOptions" class="k-autocomplete" data-bind="kendoTreeView: { dataSource: $data, dataTextField: 'Name', checkboxes: { checkChildren: true }, dataBound: $parent.ExpandSection }"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone provide a little more insight or thoughts for this?

Comment: Check this and see if it is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062107/using-jquery-dynatree-with-knockout-and-breeze/18062730#18062730 - also if you could provide a fiddle that would help, as i haven't used Kendo TreeView before and it is hard to imagine what you are trying to do or bind against without your custom binding

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to bind to javascript datasource for reducing the number of AJAX calls. Please refer to the example on this page for further details.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/local-data.html